# How to make Banshee notification in Ubuntu 11.04 show the playlist by default

Tags: banshee, notification

I want to be able to play music with Banshee without the need to open it after i have already made my Playlist. For the moment i have to open Banshee at least one time for the playlist to appear in the sound options in the bar. If i do not open Banshee the playlist option does not appear. The following images show both, Unity 3D and Gnome 2.x:

[image]

[image]

And how it should look no matter if i open or not Banshee:

[image]

As you can see here, the playlist option appears and i can select my playlist playing the songs in it without having to open Banshee for it. More friendlier. And if you need to edit the playlist then that would be a reason to open Banshee (Apart from the many others of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems a very interesting idea. Unfortunately Ask Ubuntu isn't the place for it - I would suggest you either post it on [Ubuntu Brainstorm](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/) or file a wishlist "bug" against [the Sound Menu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/indicator-sound/+filebug).